# MongoDB aggregation framework: single element or empty array conversion to number

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to know which is the shortest and cleanest way to do this conversion using the mongo aggregation framework:

```
{ total: [ { value: 200} ] }

to

{ total: 200 }
```

and:

```
{ total: [] }

to

{ total: 0 }
```

This is, `total` should be the value of the `value` field (there will be always one in the array) or zero if the `total` array is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get first array element and [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) to provide the default value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            total: { $ifNull: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$total.value", 0 ] }, 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3VPVpr3Gt7-)